# Is there a database method other than oData?

Tags: database, odata

I wonder if there is a database and method other than oData. I wonder if there is a way to connect in real time like oData rather than importing a csv file.

Answer (score 1):

Although your question is not very clear, I'm assuming by your reference to OData that you're looking at External Objects/Salesforce Connect.

If so, you should reference the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.salesforce_connect_apex.htm&type=5), which provides additional details on how to build a custom adapter in Apex to support connecting to non-OData external data sources.

Note also that cross-org connections with Salesforce Connect [don't use OData](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.salesforce_connect_xorg.htm&type=5) but directly access the Salesforce REST API.